# How to stack two columns of a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to stack two columns on top of each other

So I have Left and Right values in one column each, and want to combine them into a single one. How do I do this in Python?
I'm working with Pandas Dataframes.

Basically from this

```
  Left Right
0  20   25
1  15   18
2  10   35
3  0     5
```

To this:

```
  New Name
0  20   
1  15   
2  10   
3  0    
4  25
5  18
6  35
7  5
```

It doesn't matter how they are combined as I will plot it anyway, and the new column name also doesn't matter because I can rename it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a list of the cols, and call squeeze to anonymise the data so it doesn't try to align on columns, and then call concat on this list, passing ignore_index=True creates a new index, otherwise you'll get the names as index values repeated:

```
cols = [df[col].squeeze() for col in df]
pd.concat(cols, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Many options, `stack`, `melt`, `concat`, ...

Here's one:

```
>>> df.melt(value_name='New Name').drop('variable', 1)
   New Name
0        20
1        15
2        10
3         0
4        25
5        18
6        35
7         5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `np.ravel`:

```
import numpy as np

out = pd.DataFrame(np.ravel(df.values.T), columns=['New name'])
print(out)

# Output
   New name
0        20
1        15
2        10
3         0
4        25
5        18
6        35
7         5
```

**Update**

If you have only 2 cols:

```
out = pd.concat([df['Left'], df['Right']], ignore_index=True).to_frame('New name')
print(out)

# Output
   New name
0        20
1        15
2        10
3         0
4        25
5        18
6        35
7         5
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `unstack`

```
df2 = df.unstack()
# recreate index
df2.index = np.arange(len(df2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `masking`.

```
# Your data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Left":[20,15,10,0], "Right":[25,18,35,5]})

# Masking columns to ravel
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"New Name":np.ravel(df[["Left","Right"]])})

df2

   New Name
0        20
1        25
2        15
3        18
4        10
5        35
6         0
7         5
```

Answer (score -2):

I ended up using this solution, seems to work fine

```
df1 = dfTest[['Left']].copy()
df2 = dfTest[['Right']].copy()
df2.columns=['Left']
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2],ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Seems very memory intensive, you are using 3 dataframes, which if they are big is very inefficient. You might wanna try and understand other solutions here that edit an existing dataframe.

Comment: fair enough, I will definitely check out the other answers

Comment: Check the two most upvoted, best bet, they both work, just take some time open up documentation to understand them.